# Usage of word "Fugitive"

Tags: word-usage

Few days back I came across a sentence, which in my opinion, had used the word "Fugitive" in incorrect fashion. Since I'm not a native speaker..I would like someone to check whether this usage is correct or not.

" We are all trying to be **fugitive** from this pandemic."

is the usage of "fugitive" in above sentence sentence correct? Please help me. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't sound correct to me. Could you please provide a link to the website where you read this and/or more context?

Comment: Look in a dictionary.  Did you find a definition of "fugitive" that fits your example?

Comment: It's a hair odd, but not technically incorrect.

Comment: We are all trying to **flee** the pandemic. Flee, the verb: run away from.

Comment: _Fugitive_ is today most often a noun, but it is valid as an adjective. So the sentence works grammatically and semantically. I can't imagine a native English speaker saying it though.

Comment: @ColinFine And make sure you don't agree with flee the pandemic. fugitives are associated with crimes or prison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common use of “fugitive from” in recent years is “fugitive from justice”. Being a fugitive from a place (e.g., North Carolina) or a chain gang also shows up. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fugitive+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfugitive%20from%3B%2Cc0

To be a fugitive from a pandemic, or to be fugitive from a pandemic, may be grammatical, but what does it mean? That we are trying to avoid getting Covid-19? That we are trying to get away from restrictions imposed by health authorities? That we are trying to go to places with lower transmission rates? To carry on our lives in spite of risks, inconveniences, and restrictions?

One must conclude it’s really ambiguous at best, but probably meaningless.

Answer (score -2):

It can be translated as 'runaway' or 'refugee' - the one, who want to run away and not to be infested/have ill